# How do I make the filling in pain aux raisins / danish pastry

Tags: pastry, vanilla, custard

I'm making pain aux raisin, but would like some help making the jelly like filling that goes in between.

The recipe [here](http://frenchfood.about.com/od/breadandpastry/r/painauraisin.htm) describes the filling as frangipane, yet when I make it, it is not as jelly like as I would like, and ends up being quite soggy.

I would describe the filling I am expecting to make as more like vanilla custard, with a kind of jelotine texture.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that I think will solve your problem.

1. Use powdered sugar instead of granulated.  I find that makes for a much smoother end product and a silkier mouth feel.
2. Cream the butter and sugar together first and then add the nuts and other ingredients.  This will add some fluffiness as the creamed butter/sugar mixture will allow it hold a little more air.
3. Add another egg (or just an extra yolk). This will create a thicker end product and allow it to set harder at the end.
4. add almonds to a custard filling recipe.  You can side step your entire problem by picking out a pudding or custard recipe that fits what you want and adding course chopped almonds to it, or on top of it. It ain't authentic but it works every time.

Also: A link I found that most closely resembles the way I make [it](http://www.joepastry.com/category/pastry-components/frangipane/), that might help you out.

Comment: Thanks sarge_smith, I'll give those tips a try next time!

Answer (score 0):

That is called 'pastry cream'. In yotuve, look for 'pastry cream by Gretchen's bakery'. Hope that helps.